# What would Jacob Palmer's (Ryan Gosling's) accent in Crazy Stupid Love be classified as?

Tags: dialogue, character, crazy-stupid-love

The movie [*Crazy, Stupid, Love*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1570728/) seems to be shot primarily in California. But still Ryan Gosling has this weird accent. What would you call this accent? Is there a specific reason for this accent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's called **phony accent**.

Ryan Gosling told to ***[W magazine](http://www.wmagazine.com/services/presscenter/pressreleases/OctoberPressRelease10)*** about his infamously slurry speech,

> "As a kid I decided that a Canadian accent doesn't sound tough. I
>   thought guys should sound like Marlon Brando. So now I have a phony
>   accent that I can't shake, so it's not phony anymore. I'm going for
>   the Madonna thing, the Lady Gaga thing--a phony accent that becomes
>   your trademark."